# MySQL not using index with JOIN, WHERE and ORDER

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, sql-order-by, materialized-views

We have two tables resembling a simple tag-record structure as follows (in reality it's much more complex but this is the essence of the problem):

```
tag (A.a) | recordId (A.b)
1         | 1
2         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 2
....
```

and

```
recordId (B.b) | recordData (B.c)
1              | 123
2              | 666
3              | 1246
```

The problem is fetching ordered records with a specific tag. The obvious way of doing it is with a simple join and indexes on (PK)(A.a, A.b), (A.b), (PK)(B.b), (B.b,B.c) as such:

```
select A.a, A.b, B.c from A join B on A.b = B.b where a = 44 order by c;
```

However, this gives the unpleasant result of a filesort:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ref  | PRIMARY,b     | PRIMARY | 4       | const     |   94 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ref  | PRIMARY,b     | b       | 4       | booli.A.b |    1 | Using index                                  | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Using a huge and extremely redundant "materialized view" we can get pretty decent performance but this at the expense of complicating the business-logic, something we would like to avoid, especially since the A and B tables already are MV:s (and are needed for other queries, and infact the same queries using a UNION).

```
create temporary table C engine=innodb as (select A.a, A.b, B.c from A join B on A.b = B.b);
explain select a, b, c from C where a = 44 order by c;
```

Further complicating the situation is the fact that we have conditionals on the B-table, such as range-filters.

```
select A.a, A.b, B.c from A join B on A.b = B.b where a = 44 AND B.c > 678 order by c;
```

But we are confident we can handle this if the filesort problem goes away.

Does anyone know why the simple join in codeblock 3 above won't use the index for sorting and if we can get around the problem in some way without creating a new MV?

Below is the full SQL listing that we are using for testing.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A (a INT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(a, b), INDEX idx_A_b (b)) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE B (b INT NOT NULL, c INT NOT NULL, d VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY(b), INDEX idx_B_c (c), INDEX idx_B_b (b, c)) ENGINE=INNODB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_filler(cnt INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE _cnt INT;
        SET _cnt = 1;
        WHILE _cnt <= cnt DO
                INSERT IGNORE INTO A SELECT RAND()*100, RAND()*10000;
                INSERT IGNORE INTO B SELECT RAND()*10000, RAND()*1000, '';
                SET _cnt = _cnt + 1;
        END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

START TRANSACTION;
CALL prc_filler(100000);
COMMIT;
DROP PROCEDURE prc_filler;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE C ENGINE=INNODB AS (SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM A JOIN B ON A.b = B.b);
ALTER TABLE C ADD (PRIMARY KEY(a, b), INDEX idx_C_a_c (a, c));

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM A JOIN B ON A.b = B.b WHERE A.a = 44;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM A JOIN B ON A.b = B.b WHERE 1 ORDER BY B.c;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM A JOIN B ON A.b = B.b where A.a = 44 ORDER BY B.c;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT a, b, c FROM C WHERE a = 44 ORDER BY c;
-- Added after Quassnois comments
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM  B FORCE INDEX (idx_B_c) JOIN A ON A.b = B.b WHERE A.a = 44 ORDER BY B.c;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM A JOIN B ON A.b = B.b WHERE A.a = 44 ORDER BY B.c LIMIT 10;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT A.a, A.b, B.c FROM  B FORCE INDEX (idx_B_c) JOIN A ON A.b = B.b WHERE A.a = 44 ORDER BY B.c LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Filesorts occur on your ORDER BY clause. How is `B.c` indexed?

Comment: @jason: I have updated the SQL in the post to be a bit more readable. The indexing should be clear now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I try to reproduce this query using your scripts:

```
SELECT  A.a, A.b, B.c
FROM    A
JOIN    B
ON      A.b = B.b
WHERE   a = 44
ORDER BY
        c
```

, it completes in `0.0043 seconds` (instantly), returns `930` rows and yields this plan:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'A', 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'const', 1610, 'Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'B', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'test.A.b', 1, ''
```

It's quite efficient for such a query.

For such a query, you cannot use a single index both for filtering and sorting.

See this article in my blog for more detailed explanations:

- [**Choosing index**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/01/choosing-index/)

If you expect your query to return few records, you should use the index on `A` for filtering and then sort using filesort (like the query above does).

If you expect it to return many records (and `LIMIT` them), you need to use index for sorting and then filter:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_a_b ON a (b);
CREATE INDEX ix_b_c ON b (c)

SELECT  *
FROM    B FORCE INDEX (ix_b_c)
JOIN    A
ON      A.b = B.b
ORDER BY
        b.c
LIMIT 10;

1, 'SIMPLE', 'B', 'index', '', 'ix_b_c', '4', '', 2, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'A', 'ref', 'ix_a_b', 'ix_a_b', '4', 'test.B.b', 4, 'Using index'
```

Comment: With the real data the record-table is quite big (both in width and in number of rows, with lots of VARCHAR(255):s) and therefor the temporary table costs more as there is alot more data to copy. On our production db (8-core xeon with everything in memory) the query takes about 0.05-0.1s and a MV-test shows sub 0.01s times.

Comment: I don't get the same query plan as you printed above for the same query. Anyways, the change in ORDER doesnt really help me, sure it removes the filesort but I get the results in the wrong order!  

Also, just changing the ORDER in the original query to "B.b, B.c" removes the filesort, indicating (well, to me ;)) that it could be possible to do this without a temporary table/filesort.  

(Funny thing, I actually borrowed the SP for inserting from your blog)

Comment: @Paso: Sorry, didn't understand your task well. Create an index on `b.c` only and change the `ORDER BY` condition. I'll update it in the post now.

Comment: @Paso: I noticed :) Glad to hear you read my blog. One little note: when filling an `InnoDB` table in a procedure, always do it in a transaction, it's way faster.

Comment: @Paso: could you please post which plans do you get when running the queries?

Comment: Now I actually get the same query execution plan as in your post, must have been something funny with the indexing last time I ran it. However the execution time quickly gets pretty bad as the LIMIT increases so I'm not sure it's relevant for me. Infact I'm not sure I can use a LIMIT at all without some major rewrite of the business logic.

Comment: @Paso: again, with this layout you cannot filter **and** sort. You need two things here: filter on `B.b` and sort on `B.c`. An index cannot satisfy both: you cannot build a single range ordered both on `b` and on `c`. If you expecting **few** values, you better filter a range using index on `B.b` and the sort the selected values, since sorting few values is fast. Otherwise select ordered data from the index on `B.c` and then just filter them using index on `A.b`. This will require selecting all values from the index on `B.c` in their order, and without a `LIMIT` it will take constant time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I will have to go the MV way with the added complexity that means.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm! Over data set of about 3 million records in table A and about a million in table B, queries used to run about 2 minutes, and now they execute in no time at all! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`select A.a, A.b, B.c from A join B on A.b = B.b where a = 44 order by c;`

If you alias the columns, does that help? Example:

```
 SELECT 
 T1.a AS colA, 
 T2.b AS colB, 
 T2.c AS colC 
 FROM A AS T1 
 JOIN B AS T2 
 ON (T1.b = T2.b) 
 WHERE 
 T1.a = 44 
 ORDER BY colC;
```

The only changes I made were:

- I put the join conditions in parenthesis
- The join conditions and where conditions are based on table columns
- The ORDER BY condition is based on the resulting table column
- I aliased the result table columns and the queried tables to (hopefully) make it more clear when I was using one or the other (and more clear to the server. You neglect to refer to your columns in two places in your original query).

I know your real data is more complex, but I assume that you provided a simple version of the query because the problem is at that simple level.

Comment: I'm afraid not, your query gives exactly the same EXPLAIN result.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to join the two tables? What I mean is, do the two tables link up where each row is a full result based on the query, or is more like each row has the data needed from both tables? I ask because if the two tables are not actually tied together in such a way that a join is required, you might consider a UNION instead. With a UNION, the queries are completely independent and thus no sub-queries or temporary tables or anything else taxing needs to happen.

Comment: I don't really understand. The tables are JOINed over A.b = B.b and I need the data from B for each A matching a condition, how would a UNION help here? 

For completeness; no I dont need all the data, only the data from B. See the tag-example at the top of the question, that should explain everything as precisely as I can.